# Is there a way to create "matrix" object with certain number of "empty" entries?

Tags: javascript, object

For example, I have some arrays (they can be changed, so there will be more or less elements)

```
let objKeys = [a,b,c];
let objValues = [1,2,3];
```

I have to create an object and fill it with keys and values from the arrays. At the end I need to have next object:

```
let obj = {
  a : 1,
  b : 2,
  c : 3
}
```

so I would like to create an empty matrix-object which I'll fill in later. 
There is a known way to create an empty array:

```
new Array(number)
```

maybe there is a similar way to create an empty object with for example null keys and values?

Comment: What exactly is a "null key"? You can create an empty object with `let obj = {};`. Objects don't have a `length` like arrays do, so there is nothing to initialize. Maybe if you explain what you want to do with such an object we could provide a better suggestion.

Comment: An array is an object with numeric keys, so when you create so-called empty array it has keys from 0 to length... How is it possible to create an object with null keys? Keys should be unique

Comment: @DmitryReutov: It actually does not. If you do `new Array(5)` the only thing that happens that `length` is set to `5`. The keys `0`, `1`, etc don't exist.

Comment: @FelixKling, Thats true, i was not precise enough in my analogy

Comment: In fact I just needed a clue how to glue two arrays to one object, but wanted to do it in exotic way... I knew there is no particular method or constructor for this. Also I've forgotten keys in object can't repeat. However we probably may create object of arrays like { [null: null], [null: null], [null: null] } and then merge them with Object.assign(), for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for this with `Object.fromEntries` and `map` methods that will take two arrays with keys and values and return new object as a result.

```js
let objKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let objValues = [1, 2, 3];

const zip = (a, b) => Object.fromEntries(a.map((k, i) => [k, b[i]]))
console.log(zip(objKeys, objValues))
```